# How to Replace Conditions in an association when upgrading to Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

In my Rails app, enrolled_lessons returns the lessons a user enrolled in. There's a condition in it so it only returns the published lessons. The following code worked in Rails **3.2**:

```
#user.rb
 has_many :enrollings, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :enrolled_lessons, through: :enrollings, source: :lesson, :conditions => {published: true}
```

How can I update this code for Rails **4.1**? I tried the following:

```
has_many :enrolled_lessons, -> {where(lesson: {published: true})}, through: :enrollings, source: :lesson
```

But when I call user.enrolled_lessons, I just get an error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing
>   FROM-clause entry for table "lesson" LINE 1: ...N "lessons"."id" =
>   "enrollings"."lesson_id" WHERE "lesson"."...
>                                                                ^ : SELECT "lessons".* FROM "lessons" INNER JOIN "enrollings" ON
>   "lessons"."id" = "enrollings"."lesson_id" WHERE "lesson"."published" =
>   't'...

Comment: Provide the source associations in your User model for a more accurate response. But right off the bat I can tell that `{where(lesson: {published: true})}` could be written as `where('lessons.published = true').references(:lesson)`

Comment: awesome! i went ahead a posted it as an answer (please accept), glad that was all it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change

```
 {where(lesson: {published: true})}
```

to

```
 where('lessons.published = true').references(:lesson)
```